# Merging standard ner Model with the custom ner Model

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am training existing standard model for named entity recognition with custom data.After training the model,It is forgetting old entity which was already there in the standard model.I want to merge the custom ner data with the standard model ner data. For example,It should recognize my custom data(e.g-Product,Family) tag along with the entity of Standard model(e.g- Person,ORG,GPE).Also how should I improve reliability of the model with less dataset.Model is predicting correctly for the trained data but failing for the completely new data. I want to leave entity as blank if test data is not there in the Model,but it is predicting wrongly with some incorrect tag. Suggest me some solution for this.I am using the code that is given on the official site of spacy ner.

Comment: This is known as the "catastrophic forgetting" problem. See the docs with suggestions and an example script here: https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type

Comment: What is the solution for this?